# Call twice timeupdate

Tags: javascript, jquery

have problem to call twice timeupdate. 
My code is:

```
$("video").on(
    "timeupdate",
    function(event){
        alert('work');
    }
);
```

it work but if I do this:

```
$('#video').html( $('#newVideo').html());
```

previous code dont work.

I try next way also not work:

1. `<video id="video">`
2. `$(document).on( "timeupdate", 'video',

   $(document).delegate('video',

   $("video").bind(,

   $( "video" ).live(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is:

```
function initPlayer () {
    var player = $(document).find('video')[0];
    if (player) {
        player.addEventListener('timeupdate', function () {
            alert('work');
        }, false)
    }
}
```

must .find video tag again after changes and before call function for ex. in this way:

```
$( "#button" ).click(function() {  
    $('#video').html( $('#newVideo').html());
    initPlayer();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `.on()` on an element higher up the heirarchy to ensure the event binding works for any element under it matching the selector - whether that element is currently existing or not.

```
// this will work for all <video> elements within the document object
$(document).on("timeupdate", 'video', function(event){
    alert('work');
});
// if possible change 'document' to something that is
// closer up in the hierarchy to the video elements
```

Comment: this not work for timeupdate. i try also: `$(document).on("timeupdate", 'video',
            $(document).delegate('video',
            $("video").bind(
            $( "video" ).live(`