# Why does html5-video event timeupdate fires twice on Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, html5-video, dom-events

html5-video event `timeupdate` fires twice on Chrome browser.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-k2WSCIexGzOj3Euiig+TlR8gA0EmPjuc79OEeY5L45g="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <video id="video">
            <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
        </video>
        <button id="button">Update time</button>
        <script>
            $( document ).ready(function() {
                var vid = document.getElementById("video")
                vid.addEventListener("timeupdate", timeUpdate, false);
                
                $("#button").on("click", buttonClick);
                
                function timeUpdate(e){
                    console.log("timeUpdate");
                }
                
                function buttonClick(e){
                    console.log("buttonClick");                 
                    vid.currentTime = 1;
                }
            });         
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

2. Click on button
3. Check result (buttonClick x 1, timeUpdate x 2)

Any ideas ?))

Comment: Have you checked the answer of this stackoverflow question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511253/call-twice-timeupdate

Comment: Yes, I have, but answer is not helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An event you are looking for is not a `timeupdate` event, pick a `seeked` event.

When you change a current time position there is a `seeking` happens, and when the position is changed - `seeked` is called.

Maybe, one of those `seeking` events can trigger `timeupdate` twice through [bubbling or capturing](https://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) but I doubt. Timeupdate is more complicated than that. From [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/timeupdate) `

> timeupdate will be thrown between about 4Hz and 66Hz

Which means it varies depending on a browser and a system you use and a load of the particular system and has nothing to do with a `currentTime` change, despite the fact that it is stated so in some documentations. In general, it is going to be triggered from 1 to 4 times per second. (it was assumed that 250ms is more than enough to update a display and more frequent updates are a waste of energy)
Firefox may fire the event every frame which gives you an impression that it works once per second. [`timeupdate` frequency in different browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678177/how-often-does-the-timeupdate-event-fire-for-an-html5-video)

Talking about current case:
In Chrome case, the event could be fired twice because 4Hz frequency has been chosen.

> 4Hz is 2 times the Nyquist frequency for 1 second (1Hz) used for
>   digital sampling

You may want to take a look at different frame rates and DF/NDF to be more precise on currentTime selection.

Also you can use this [page](https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html) to take a look video API in action.

Comment: Thanks a lot! "seeked" event is perfect.

Comment: seeked event also is called twice!!! 
even floating point is same.